# CMB2 Multicheck Display Selected Options

Tags: php, wordpress, meta-boxes

I am trying to display the selected options from my functioning CMB2 multicheck metabox. Currently this is returned on the front-end:

**check1check2**

I am trying to return:

**Open Ceiling Drop Ceiling**

What am I missing? I could do this in a different way, but it's become a bit of a vendetta for me. Any help is greatly appreciated!

My metabox is here and appears in the appropriate page edit area:

```
$zf_ind_boxes->add_field( array(
 'name'     => esc_html__( 'Fan Types', 'cmb2' ),
 'desc'     => esc_html__( 'For Wassup content. Check all that apply.', 'cmb2' ),
 'id'       => $prefix . 'ind_fan_types',
 'type'     => 'multicheck',
 'label_cb' => 'get_the_labels',
 'options'  => array(
     'check1' => 'Open Ceiling',
     'check2' => 'Drop Ceiling',
     'check3' => 'Spot Cooling',
    )
) );
```

In my template I have:

```
$array = get_post_meta($metafield_id, 'zf_ind_fan_types', true);

if($array) {
  foreach ($array as $key => $value){
    echo $value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want display checked values at front-end just replace your section with this one below.

```
'options' => array(
    'Open Ceiling' => 'Open Ceiling',  //key => value
    'Drop Ceiling' => 'Drop Ceiling',  //key => value
    'Spot Cooling' => 'Spot Cooling',  //key => value
    )
```

Value is hardcoded - so it isn't saved in database, in database is saved only key